# Using entries in database table column to populate Django Combo Box

Tags: python, django, combobox

I am trying to create a *drop down menu* using *Django* field *"Choices"*, however for this I  have to hand code the value in python code.Is there any way by which I can make *Django* to take the *Dropdown* list entries from column of a particular table. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which is specifically for that.

Comment: In my case the column from which I want to populate the value is defined in another app.From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) I have to mention the required column name in "to_field_name".I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: It is completely irrelevant what app the model is defined in. Just do `ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyOtherModel.objects.all(), to_field_name="column_with_the_value')`.